# Dynamically adding x number of days to a date in PHP

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a scenario where I have to add x number if days to a variable containing date. This x will be dynamic and cannot be guessed.

Any suggestions on how I can implement this?

```
$ticket_created_on_date_time = '2016-08-31 09:55:01'
$in_between_days = 2;
```

Comment: convert the date to a unix timestamp, then add x * 86400 seconds, then convert back to date (if necessary)

Comment: Thanks a lot guys. It was a big help. Thanks again. :-)

Comment: @chris85 please post an answer & I will accept it.

Comment: I think the best answer is from @walthfish

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use math and the `strtotime` function to get a date in the past/future. Something like:

```
strtotime($ticket_created_on_date_time) + (86400 * $in_between_days)
```

(86400 is one day in seconds)
....or

```
strtotime($ticket_created_on_date_time . '+ ' . $in_between_days . ' days')
```

Demo: https://eval.in/634187

Comment: OP only wants to add x days - no mention of past dates

Comment: Simple math operation, `+` instead of `-`.

Comment: @TheOneandOnlyChemistryBlob thanks a lot for helping first. Your quick reply mattered..... :-)

Answer (score 3):

A quick example:

```
<?php
$date = new DateTime($ticket_created_on_date_time);
$date->add(new DateInterval(sprintf('P%dD', $in_between_days)));
echo $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'); //output: 2016-09-02 09:55:01
```

More details in http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.add.php

Answer (score 1):

You should be doing it like this,

```
<?php
$date = new DateTime($ticket_created_on_date_time);
$date->modify("+2 day");
echo $date->format("r");
```

**Edit** - You can modify dynamically like this:

```
$date->modify(sprintf("%u day",$day_diff));
```